# n98-magerun.phar autocomplete script

Tags: magento-1

I am trying to use the autocomplete code for N98-MageRun in my OS-X 10.9.2:
https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/tree/master/autocompletion/bash

I performed the following steps but without luck:

1> Copied the autocomplete file to home directory

```
sudo cp ~/autocompletion/bash/bash_complete ~/.n98-magerun.phar
```

2> Added the following code to the ~/.bash_profile:

```
if [ -f ~/.n98-magerun.phar ]; then 
    . ~/.n98-magerun.phar 
fi
```

Also tried with:

```
source ~/.n98-magerun.phar
```

3> Reloaded ~/.bash_profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Unfortunately the autocompletion for magerun command is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the bash_completion script itself.
The developer fixed the issue by adding `--no-ansi` option to autocompletion.
For time being, you can use this file:
https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/blob/develop/autocompletion/bash/bash_complete